# Modifiying <clinit> with ASM

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

Hello I have a little problem with ASM. It produces a class with bytecode error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad instruction
Exception Details:
  Location:
    me/test/Main.<clinit>()V @0: wide
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

When i use the following code to inject code into the `<clinit>` method, which fills an static byte array with the "key" (`byte[]`) variable:

```
   if (key.length > 128)
        this.visitVarInsn(SIPUSH, key.length);
    else
        this.visitVarInsn(BIPUSH, key.length);
    this.visitVarInsn(NEWARRAY, 8);
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
        this.visitInsn(DUP);
        if (i > 127) {
            this.visitVarInsn(SIPUSH, i + 32768);
        } else if (i < 6) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    this.visitInsn(ICONST_0);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    this.visitInsn(ICONST_1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    this.visitInsn(ICONST_2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    this.visitInsn(ICONST_3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    this.visitInsn(ICONST_4);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    this.visitInsn(ICONST_5);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Logic mistake!");
                    break;
            }
        }
        else {
            this.visitVarInsn(BIPUSH, i);
        }
        if (key[i] < 6 && key[i] >= 0) {
            switch (key[i]) {
                case 0:
                    this.visitInsn(ICONST_0);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    this.visitInsn(ICONST_1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    this.visitInsn(ICONST_2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    this.visitInsn(ICONST_3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    this.visitInsn(ICONST_4);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    this.visitInsn(ICONST_5);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Logic mistake!");
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            this.visitVarInsn(BIPUSH, key[i]);
        }
        this.visitInsn(BASTORE);
```

Comment: @Holger the key is always 2048 bytes. and the thing with 32768 i will check

Comment: @Holger this is messed up... i removed the +32768 and this happens: original bytecode: http://pastebin.com/5Rr85SpS modified bytecode: http://pastebin.com/sg0yLTgb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main cause for your incorrect code is your multiple misuse of `visitVarInsn`.

`visitVarInsn` is designed for instructions whose argument is the index of a local variable. Since it depends on the particular instruction, how the argument is encoded into the instruction, this method produces incorrect code when used together with instructions, it is not designed for. So, instead of

```
this.visitVarInsn(NEWARRAY, 8);
```

you should use

```
this.visitIntInsn(NEWARRAY, Opcodes.T_BYTE);
```

The same applies to the incorrect invocations of `this.visitVarInsn(SIPUSH, key.length);` and `this.visitVarInsn(BIPUSH, key.length);`, but in these cases there are additional errors in your duplicated code, e.g. right your first occurrence,

```
if (key.length > 128)
    this.visitVarInsn(SIPUSH, key.length);
else
    this.visitVarInsn(BIPUSH, key.length);
```

will break, when the constant value is exactly `128`. Further, `this.visitVarInsn(SIPUSH, i + 32768);` contains a spurious `+ 32768` additionally to the use of the wrong method.

Generally, you should not repeat this code for generating an optimal instruction. Do either, create a utility method whose correctness you have to prove only once, or use an existing method. E.g., if you inherit from `InstructionAdapter` rather than directly from `MethodVisitor`, you can use [`iconst(int)`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/commons/InstructionAdapter.html#iconst-int-) which will automatically generate `ICONST_x`, `BIPUSH`, `SIPUSH` or `LDC`. Or, when you inherit from `GeneratorAdapter` instead, you can use [`push(int)`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/commons/GeneratorAdapter.html#push-int-) to achieve the same.

So using [`GeneratorAdapter`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/?org/objectweb/asm/commons/GeneratorAdapter.html), the code would be as simple as

```
push(key.length);
newArray(Type.BYTE_TYPE);
for(int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
    this.visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP);
    push(i);
    push(key[i]);
    visitInsn(Opcodes.BASTORE);
}
```

Comment: one last problem: this (http://pastebin.com/zdCDgecK) code produces http://pastebin.com/RK8wduGk instead of http://pastebin.com/rUsG6wja (compiler). how can I fix that?

Comment: The code is identical. The labels do not appear, because they are unused. In the compiler output, they appear, because the method has attached debug information regarding the local variables and their scopes (the scope information refers to the labels). You can generate similar debug information using [`visitLocalVariable`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitLocalVariable-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.objectweb.asm.Label-org.objectweb.asm.Label-int-), but do you want that? As said, the executable code is the same.

Comment: You may compile the source without debug information (`javac`: using `-g:none`) to get a similar result than the generated code). By the way, that generating code still incorrectly uses `visitVarInsn` for `NEWARRAY` which seems to happen to do the right thing now, but can break in surprising ways if something (even apparently unrelated) changes.

Comment: That is unrelated to the code you have posted. For class files with version 51 or newer, `StackMapTable` attributes are mandatory (relevant if the code has branches, see also [“What is stackmap table in jvm bytecode?”](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37310409/2711488)). ASM can generate them for you, see [“Expecting a stackmap frame”](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28275631/2711488) or [“How do I overcome the “VerifyError:Expecting a stackmap frame” for a JDK 7/8 application?”](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34507079/2711488).

Comment: If I set COMPUTE_FRAMES in the class writer this occures: http://pastebin.com/qeEL23fb

Comment: Do you [invoke `visitMaxs` at the end](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28989866/2711488)? If that’s not the issue, I suppose to open a new question.

Comment: I invoked it at the beginning. I changed it to invoke at the end and it worked! Thank you very much!